# New Rules to validate US social security number(SSN)

Tags: algorithm, validation

I need to validate US SSN number. Currently I have below rules:

1. Should be 9 digits long.
2. Not allowed are SSNs with all zeros in any digit group (000-xx-####, ###-00-####, ###-xx-0000).
3. Not allowed are SSNs with Area Numbers (First 3 digits) 000, 666 and 900-999.
4. Not allowed are SSNs from 987-65-4320 to 987-65-4329.

And there are few rules to validate Group Code(-xx-). I have verified in below Site but I couldn't understand the logic of "Group Code"?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/ssnvalidator.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? The page you linked there already has an **incredibly** detailed description of the algorithm for validating an SSN, it even has a **flowchart**! If you want help with actual code, you should tag your question with the language you are interested in, and ask a more specific question. The [algorithm] tag seems inappropriate here given the quality of that link...

Comment: given link is actually it is OLD Post and now as per CMS they removed the relation with group local. only the 4 rules given above are latest SSN rules.

Comment: Are you a government department? If not, why are you asking people for their SSN? http://cpsr.org/issues/privacy/ssn-faq/

Comment: i was asking for the rules to validate the SSN number not the People SSN number.. I am really sorry if you misunderstood..

Answer (score 5):

The SSA changed the rules for issuance of SSNs effective June 25, 2011.  See http://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html.

The rules for SSNs issued until the day before are outlined here: http://www.ssa.gov/employer/ssnweb.htm

I suppose that for SSNs to be accurately validated, you would need to know their issuance dates.  Prior to June 25, 2011, use the old rules.  On June 25, 2011 or after, use the new rules.